# Why is CS0246 "The type or namespace name 'Name' could not be found" C# error so confusing?

Tags: c#, .net, using

Here's the scenario. I create a new class library project in Visual Studio, add some classes. Then at some point I decide that I need some class to be marked with `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute` and I write the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDataContractClass {}
```

and when I hit compile I see the following error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataMember' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Okay, the problem is I forgot to add `using` directive to make the class visible. I add

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

to the same file above the class but the problem doesn't go away until I add a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization` in the Project Explorer.

This is very confusing. Why do I have to add the same thing two times in different places and ***see the same error message regardless of which of the two steps I missed***?

My question is the following. Is this just ***badly designed error diagnostics*** or is there some ***fundamental reason*** why missing any of the two above steps leads to the same error emitted by the C# compiler?

Comment: Although you do get the same error, if you add the reference first, the VS IDE does offer some help in the form of a small context sensitive menu which will add the using statement for you (alt-shift-f10) is the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It's very easy to blame the language/compiler when you're first starting out and making silly mistakes..

Comment: @MattDavey: Please note I don't blame the compiler, I just say it is confusing and ask if it's a design fault or is it backed by some fundamental reasoning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing the same thing twice. Any assembly may contain types in any namespace. A `using` statement is just a shortcut to referencing types in a namespace - and those types could be supplied by any assembly.

The general convention in system supplied assemblies is that assemblies with the same name as a namespace will contain a large number of types within that namespace - but there's no way for the compiler to know which assembly you've forgotten to reference if it can't resolve a type name - it can't even know (until you add the right assembly) that DataContract is in the `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace.

---

To have it improve the diagnostics as you want, it would need to, when compiling:

- know the error messages that were emitted during the *previous* compilation attempt
- know the previous state and current state of the source files that have changed
- assume that any text added in between was your attempt to resolve any/all previous errors
- and then change it's search strategy so that it only searches for previously unresolved type names in new using statements.

Comment: I think this is the key bit of information for the OP: unlike in the Java world, in .NET the namespace for a type and the name of the assembly for the type are not related as far as the framework is concerned.  It's only a widely-used convention that make namespaces and assembly names similar.

Comment: @Michael: Well Java doesn't really *have* the concept of an assembly, but the same two steps are required: put a library in the classpath, add an import statement.

Comment: @Jon: My point is that Java needs to find the class in some container, and the namespace is an important part of that. In .NET the namespace really has nothing to do with where the framework looks for a type. You might be surprised at how long it took me to figure out that to be found my Java classes *had* to be in a particular file system path underneath the directory in the classpath. I'm not saying there are fewer 'steps' in Java, but that `import` influences how Java looks for the class, while a `using` statement in .NET doesn't.

Comment: @Michael: No, the namespace in Java is *not* an important part of which "container" has the class file. It's an important part of how Java looks for a class *within* a container, but not which container it uses. So the class for foo.bar.Baz could be in foo.jar or xyz.jar. If you think of jar files and assemblies as very loosely equivalent, C# and Java work exactly the same. The difference is that in Java, class files can be "loose" within a the file system, but I'd call that looking "within" the container, which in this case would be a directory.

Comment: @Jon: I know I'm not being rigorous here, but I think it's a mental model that works for some people. It does at least for one person - me. I know that when I'm working in Java (admittedly that's not much, so I'm probably dealing with mechanics that are dealt with by tools for most people), I need to concern myself with where the class is in terms of the namespace (whether that namespace is a path inside a jar or on the file system). I don't need to do that for .NET - I need to know where the assembly is, but the namespace isn't involved in that (except as a naming convention possibly).

Comment: @Michael: Why do you need to know where a class is inside a jar file any more than you need to know where it is within an assembly? Think of a jar file or dll as an opaque blob that you can reference. You only need to concern yourself with this sort of thing when *building* a jar file or referring to class files in the file system - and if you think of "one classpath entry" as an opaque blob too (whether that's a file system directory or a jar file), the difference goes away even more.

Comment: @Michael: To put it another way: suppose you suddenly found out that *actually* .NET assemblies were zip files with a layer of obfuscation. Would that change how you think about them when you add a reference? In terms of *referring to a library*, the package name is just as unimportant as the namespace is in C#.

Answer (score 5):

You get the same error message because as far as the compiler is concerned it's the same problem: it can't find the type you're referring to. Without knowing which type you're trying to refer to, it doesn't know whether you're missing a `using` directive or a reference - it's a catch-22 situation.

How do you think the compiler should know whether it can't find the type because you're missing a `using` directive or because you're missing a reference? Should it look through every type in *every* namespace in every reference, to let you know that you're missing a `using` directive? That could still be incorrect, because you might actually mean an entirely different type, in a different namespace. (In fact, things like Intellisense and ReSharper are willing to offer you options - the compiler can't really do that.)

Now assuming *you* know which type you mean, the problem is easy to solve, because you can check both aspects:

- Make sure you've got a reference to the appropriate assembly
- Make sure you've got an appropriate `using` directive

*You've* got all the information required to find out what's wrong. The compiler hasn't.

Of course, if *you* don't know which type you mean either, then it's pretty unreasonable to expect the compiler to.

Comment: So actually there are three options for the error, 1 - missing using, 2 - missing reference, 3 - PEBKAC problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think that the error message was pretty descriptive of both the problem and the solution. The warning states `are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`, and you were indeed missing both.

As for why this isn't two separate warnings, sure, the complier could see if there is a reachable type by that name, and issue a `using` warning it there is, but issue a `reference` warning if there isn't. but why should it?
That would be slow, and it will almost never bring extra information on the table, as the programmer usually knows better what he/she was trying to do than the compiler.

To side-step the issue, ReSharper has a nice feature that will automatically add the reference if and where it's needed.